# Rails PaperClip `method_missing': undefined method `has_attatched_file'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am encountering an error involving PaperClip at runtime. I have followed the instructions as stated by the Paperclip github page. Details involving paperclip are stated below. Is there something I might have missed?

**Error Log**

`/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in 'method_missing': undefined method 'has_attatched_file' for Vehicle (call 'Vehicle.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NoMethodError)`

**Enviroment**

- **IDE**: [Cloud 9](https://c9.io) (Online IDE which is hosted on Ubuntu)
- **Rails Version**: 4.1.6
- **Ruby Version**:  2.1.5p273
- **imagemagick**: installed

**vehicle.rb**

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attatched_file  :main_photo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", "thumb" => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png" 
  validates_attatchment_content_type :main_photo, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/   
end
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.3"
```

Comment: did you mean `has_attached_file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a typo dude. You need `has_attached_file` instead of `has_attatched_file`.

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file  :main_photo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", "thumb" => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png" 
  validates_attatchment_content_type :main_photo, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/   
end
```

Comment: You are my hero! I bashed my head in for days hah.